# issue with a background image in IE8

Tags: css, internet-explorer-8, padding

I've tried various fixes but I'm still unable to solve this rather irritating issue in IE8. I have a container Div containing two child Divs, one floated left and the other floated right. There is a background image applied to the container DIV and this renders as it should in ie6 and ie7, however in ie8 it just will not appear. I think the issue is that the top padding applied to both child elements is not being respected/applied by ie8, and since the background image has a height of only 11px, the two child elements are sitting flush up against the parent DIV and therefore the background image is not displaying.

Here's my code and CSS:

```
       <div id="bottom">

        <div class="moduletable_footermenu">
     <ul class="menu"><li class="item56"><a href="/~domain/index.php?option=com_content&amp;view=article&amp;id=52&amp;Itemid=56"><span>Class Schedule</span></a></li><li class="item57"><a href="/~domain/index.php?option=com_content&amp;view=section&amp;layout=blog&amp;id=4&amp;Itemid=57"><span>Testimonials</span></a></li><li class="item58"><a href="/~domain/index.php?option=com_content&amp;view=article&amp;id=53&amp;Itemid=58"><span>Contact</span></a></li><li id="current" class="active item59"><a href="/~domain/index.php?option=com_xmap&amp;sitemap=1&amp;Itemid=59"><span>Sitemap</span></a></li></ul>  </div>

   <div class="moduletable">
     Copyright &#169; -2010 sitename   </div>


  </div><!--end of bottom -->
```

CSS:

```
div#bottom {
clear:both;
width:1014px;
margin:0px auto; 
background:url(../images/footer-shadow.gif) top no-repeat;
}

div#bottom div.moduletable {
width:400px;
float:left;
font-size:0.9em;
color:#ccc;
padding:15px 0px 15px 0px;
}

div .moduletable_footermenu{
float:right;
padding:15px 30px 15px 0px;
}
```

It must be something specific to IE8 and probably something quite small causing the issue here - can anyone please spot the problem ? I just can't seem to solve it no matter what I try.

Grateful for any help.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried Firefox and Chrome/Safari? Did you use standard DOCTYPE? They should behave the same way as IE8 did.

In standard CSS, container's height will not be adjusted to the height of the floated boxes; I will expect IE8 to not showing the container (height=0px) being the fact it's a more standard-compatible browser.

If you are looking for effects in IE6/7 in a standard-compatible browser, search for 'clearfix' solutions.

Comment: Hi,My background image renders properly in Firefox and Chrome without any issues, so I don't think it's the height issue you refer to.

Comment: Actually i had made a silly error with the if IE8 declaration, so it was not pointing to the correct css file. Have corrected that and now IE8 displays correctly.